# S.M.A.R.T attribute 0x04 start/stop count for external hard-drives

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, smart

I'm currently testing my new usb hard-disk, a 3TB Toshiba Canvio Basic. I use Hard Disk Sentinel to check its SMART attributes and other parameters, and i noticed that the start/stop count for this drive has already reached 197 in just a few days. Now, i know that this is probably by design, or maybe not. I have no experience on external hard-drives, but my oldest internal sata drives have a start/stop count of around 7000 after 6-7 years! Am i just being too paranoid? Could you provide the value of this attribute for your drives?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't that value depend on whether you have your system set do automatically power down drives when they are not being used?

Comment: It's a possibility, i've just started to do some tests. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I think i got the solution: my drive is working just fine, the problem is Hard Disk Sentinel itself. It keeps polling the drive every 5 minutes, and since it takes less then 5 minutes for my hard disk to enter into sleep/standby mode, the program is actually incrementing the start/stop count by awakening the disk every time it reads the SMART data! Fortunately you can modify this behaviour by setting the polling frequency in the advanced options. It solved my problem perfectly!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: To be clear, do you mean you solved the problem by increasing the HD Sentinel polling frequency, which has the effect of keeping the drive awake (and spinning)?  That wouldn't be an ideal solution for a drive that's idle most of the time, that the user wants to be asleep most of the time.